# keeping reference between two states in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to keep a reference between two states, one is array of objects, and the second one is hash table of the objects in the array.

vanilla javascript example:

```
const state1 = [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}];
const state2 = state1[0];
```

now, I want to change values in the state2 that will affect the state1.

```
state2.name = "bar";
console.log(state1) // output:  [{id: 1, name: 'bar'}]
console.log(state2) // output:  {id: 1, name: 'bar'}
```

how can i do that in react ?
any state has his own reference.

thanks!

```
const [state1, setState1] = useState([]);
const [state2, setState2] = useState({});

setState1([{id: 1, name: 'foo'}]);
setState2(state1[0]);
console.log(state1) // output:  [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}]
console.log(state2) // output:  {id: 1, name: 'foo'}


setState2((prevState) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      name: "bar"
    };
  });

console.log(state1) // output:  [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}]
console.log(state2) // output:  {id: 1, name: 'bar'}
```

Comment: At a glance the usual answer would be "you don't".  Why do you need to duplicate the same state in multiple places?  If what you need is a reference to `state1` then why can't you use `state1`?  What's the use case for this?

Comment: As an aside... The code shown does not produce the output shown at all.  State updates are asynchronous.  If you immediately log the state to the console after updating it then you will not see those updates.  It sounds like you're making some false assumptions which are clouding your debugging.

Comment: let's say I have an array of objects, and any object has nested objects. I don't want to use nested loops to get the specific object. I want the ability to get the object with O(1) by key.

Comment: *Objects* don't have "loops".  Objects are just data.  You can reference an array by its index, you can search for an item with operations like `find` and `filter`, etc.  It's still not clear why you want or need to duplicate your state.  But, if you *really want* to duplicate state, then after updating `state1` you would then update `state2`.  In the example shown you're only updating one of them.

Comment: I don't want to update two states manually!
I want to update one state that will affect the second state.
and yes, I can loop on objects with for..in loop, but I dont want to use it. 

paste this code in your console:

const state1 = [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}];
const state2 = state1[0];
state2.name = "bar";



and let me know what happened to state1 name after I only changed the state2 name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

The only reason your vanilla JavaScript code "worked" was because you were relying on references to objects in memory and mutating those objects.  In React you don't mutate state.  Since updating state creates a new reference, you would need to duplicate your updates to cover both state values.

But more importantly...

There's no need here to duplicate state.  And, as you're discovering, when you *duplicate data* then you also need to *duplicate logic* to manually keep that data synchronized.  For example, here you're only updating `state2`:

```
setState2((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    name: "bar"
  };
});
```

So only `state2` gets updated.  If you also want `state1` to be updated, you need to update `state1`.  For example:

```
setState1((prevState) => {
  return prevState.map((p, i) => {
    if (i === 0) { // the same magic value you already use
      return {
        ...p,
        name: "bar"
      };
    } else {
      return p;
    }
  });
});
```

And elsewhere in the component, respond to that state update:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState2(state1[0]); // here's that magic value again
}, [state1, setState2]);
```

And this additional operation is for... what purpose?  So you can conveniently reference `state2` in your code instead of referencing `state1[0]`?  Seems like unnecessary work/complexity for very little return.

Just don't duplicate your state/data/references/etc. in the first place and the problem becomes moot.  Maintain your system of record (or source of truth, if you prefer) and use that data.  Manually keeping multiple sources of data synchronized is (1) difficult and (2) unnecessary.

If you *really want to* have the same data in two state values, then as above you would just add a `useEffect` to update one when the other gets updated.  But be aware that this additional complexity is likely to cause future bugs.